# Chaining Extraction and Insertion, bracketing

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, iostream

I tried to experimenting these iostream weird behavior.

```
int value = 2;

cout << (value << 2) << endl; //output is 8
cout << (value >> 2) << endl; //output is 0
```

So what is happening here ?

Comment: Those are so-called [bit-shifts](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/).

Comment: Your confusion maybe down to the two very different meanings of the operators `<<` and `>>`, depending on what they're operating on. For integers, they are bit-shifts (as pointed out by @Blaze) but, for file- or string-streams, they are input/output operations.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica this would make a good answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion here is quite understandable! The issue is with the nature of the two `C++` operators, `<<` and `>>`. In the very early days of the language's evolution from `C`, these were *exclusively* used as so-called "bit-shift" operators, where `<<` would shift the value in an integer the given number of bits to the left, and `>>` would shift bits to the right. So, given `2` for a 16-bit integer, `value`, its binary representation would be:

```
0000000000000010
```

The expression `value << 2` shifts all bits in the integer 2 places to the *left*; any bits shifted beyond the 'top' (bit #15) are lost, and 'gaps' created on the right are filled with zeros, giving:

```
0000000000001000
```

which is the binary representation of the number `8`.

The expression `value >> 2` shifts all bits 2 places to the *right*; any bits that are shifted beyond the 'bottom' (bit #0) are lost, and gaps at the right are filled with zeros. Thus, in your case, the only `1` bit is lost (falls off the end), and the overall `value` ends up as zero.

Now, when the `C++` concept of the **stream** came along, operator symbols were needed for input to, and output from, such streams (be they *string* streams or *file* streams, like `cout` in your code). The operators `<<` and `>>` were chosen for these as they 'look' like what they are actually doing (arrow-like indicators of movement). Fortunately, the `C++` language allows *redefinition* of ***any*** operator for a specific type of variable (it's called "operator overloading") and, if you look in the `<iostream>` standard header, you will see something like this in the definition/declaration of the `ostream` class:

```cpp
ostream& operator<< (int val);
//.. similar lines for types other than int
```

This "operator overload" is coded in the standard library's source as writing a formatted version of `val` to the file represented by a given `ostream` object (like `cout`).

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

**PS:** As an exercise/thought-provoker: what would be expected to happen if the parentheses were removed from your two lines of code?

**PPS:** Regarding the use of bit-shift operators for multiplying or dividing by powers-of-2: this is lazy and potentially dangerous when a change-of-sign could take place; especially for negative numbers! See [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) (bolding mine):

> For negative a, the behavior of a << b is **undefined**.
>
> For unsigned a and for signed and non-negative a, the value of a >> b is the integer part of a/2^b.
>
> For negative a, the value of a >> b is **implementation-defined** (in most implementations, this performs arithmetic right shift, so that the result remains negative).

Comment: so what is the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In case of streams they are insertion and extraction operators. 
Otherwise they are known as LEFT AND RIGHT SHIFT OPERATORS.
Read about these from [Link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)
But for time being let me explain your output.

> (<<) (left shift) Takes two numbers, left shifts the bits of the first operand, the second operand decides the number of places to shift. Or in other words left shifting an integer “x” with an integer “y” 
>   is equivalent to multiplying x with 2^y (2 raise to power y).

Eg -

```
 a = 5//(00000101)
 a<<1
result is 10(00001010)>// here bit shifted by one position.
```

> (>>) (right shift) Takes two numbers, right shifts the bits of the first operand, the second operand decides the number of places to shift.Similarly right shifting (x>>y) is equivalent to dividing x with 2^y.

```
a = 5;//(00000101)
The result is 00000010 which is 2
printf("b>>1 = %d\n", b>>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `>>` is a [bitwise operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) of right shift.

Long answer:
Numbers in computers are generally stored in binary, when you have not 10, but only 2 digits: 0 and 1. In such a numeral system you have zero as 0, one as 1, but 2 as 10, because first digit overflows (there is no digit behind the 1), three as 11, four as 100 etc.

Many of programming languages offer some operations acting on binary representation of numbers.

There are some of them:

- bit-and `&`, which interprets each bit of number as a separate bool:

```
00000110
&
00000101
=
00000100
```

Here you see only third bit in result set to 1 because this is the only bit that is set to 1 in first two numbers.

- bit-or `|`, which is `||` operation for separate bits of operands:

```
00000110
&
00000101
=
00000111
```

Here you see 1 bit in result for any bit that is 1 in any of first two numbers.

- right shift `>>`, which "moves" all bits of a number to the right by some number of positions:

```
00110100 >> 2
=
00001101
```

- left shift `<<`, same as previous, but moves the bits to the left:

```
00000101 << 3
=
00101000
```

So originally `<<` and `>>` are bit-shift operators. But in C++ you have another feature called [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), that allows you to redefine the behaviour of some operator for your specific types. Some examples of this are `operator +` for strings that allows you to use `+` for "adding" strings like this:

```
string a = "Hello";
string b = "World";
string c = a + ", " + b;
```

Strings aren't numbers, but you still can use `+` for "adding" (or concatenatenating) them because someone already defined such overloads for `+`.

The same thing happens to `<<` and `>>`: these are just overloaded bit-shift operators defined to be called when used with `cout` and `cin` objects respectively.

Some links for further study:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm